# In Spring project unable to start Tomcat from IntlleiJ

Tags: intellij-idea

```
I have spring project. Now i am configuring Tomcat Server in IntelliJ. When i run the Tomcat from IntelliJ, it shows the following console error.



SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.weaving.AspectJWeavingEnabler#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1079)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:643)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:407)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.weaving.LoadTimeWeaverAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(LoadTimeWeaverAwareProcessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar
    at org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.setBeanClassLoader(DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.java:83)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1436)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 28 more
Jul 18, 2011 2:43:51 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextInitialized
INFO: WSSERVLET12: JAX-WS context listener initializing
Jul 18, 2011 2:43:51 PM com.sun.xml.ws.server.MonitorBase createRoot
INFO: Metro monitoring rootname successfully set to: null
Jul 18, 2011 2:43:52 PM com.sun.xml.ws.server.MonitorBase createRoot
INFO: Metro monitoring rootname successfully set to: null
Jul 18, 2011 2:43:52 PM com.sun.xml.ws.server.MonitorBase createRoot
INFO: Metro monitoring rootname successfully set to: null
Jul 18, 2011 2:43:52 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate <init>
INFO: WSSERVLET14: JAX-WS servlet initializing
Jul 18, 2011 2:43:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jul 18, 2011 2:43:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Jul 18, 2011 2:43:52 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate destroy
INFO: WSSERVLET15: JAX-WS servlet destroyed
Jul 18, 2011 2:43:52 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextDestroyed
INFO: WSSERVLET13: JAX-WS context listener destroyed
Jul 18, 2011 2:43:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive jamon.war
Jul 18, 2011 2:43:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Jul 18, 2011 2:43:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
Jul 18, 2011 2:43:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory host-manager
Jul 18, 2011 2:43:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory manager
Jul 18, 2011 2:43:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory resweb
Jul 18, 2011 2:43:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory soapui
Jul 18, 2011 2:43:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 18, 2011 2:43:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 18, 2011 2:43:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 10133 ms
Connected to server
```

Answer (score 2):

Your stacktrace says

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver': Initialization of bean
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ClassLoader [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] does NOT
>   provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. **Specify a
>   custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's
>   agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar**

Perhaps you could do as it suggests? Add a -javaagent to the VM args in the run-config.